# Custom Archive Template for Multiple Categories

Tags: categories, templates, template-hierarchy

I want to create a custom archive template for two post categories.

One of my categories is events, and the other one is courses (I have more). I already have a custom template for events (category-event.php), but I want to create another one to list both events and courses, but not include any other categories. The layout will be more or less the same as the category-event.php template. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you looking to have 1 template for events and 1 for events AND courses and a third for everything else, or 1 for events and courses and one for everything else?

Comment: Yes, I want to have one template for events and another for events AND courses, and a third for everything else. I have one already for events only (category-events.php) and for everything else (archive.php), but want to create one for events AND courses. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of would be to have the two categories you want to display together grouped under a parent category.

```
Parent Category
|----Child Category A
|----Child Category B
```

The file category-parent-category.php would by default show posts from both.
The file category-child-category-a.php would only show from a.
The file category-child-category-b.php would only show from b.
The file category.php would show from all categories.

Would that do what you want?

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! A very straightforward solution.